# need help with iphone layout with fixed tabs and scrolling content

Tags: iphone, layout, scroll, mobile-safari, fixed

I am looking to develop a webpage specifically for viewing on an iPhone/mobile browsers.  The layout would be something like this:

[image]

I would like the two tabs at the top to be fixed, i.e. they would always appear at the top of the viewport/screen, and the content in each tab to scroll (the height of the content in each tab would exceed the remaining available height, and so I would want this to scroll).

Ideally there would also be a transition on switching tabs (perhaps a simple fade would work best with the graphics capability of the iPhone), though this is not essential.

I would be grateful for any advice in getting this set up,

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Look into [JQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) it's a library that does nice animations similar to iPhone native OS.